# Can i deploy a react and mysql on a shared hosting?

Tags: deployment

this guy [Short Article](https://dev.to/crishanks/deploy-host-your-react-app-with-cpanel-in-under-5-minutes-4mf6)
deploy a react app with c-panel, but a app that doesnt connect to a db (mysql)?
can i do it the same way with a app that connected to mysql?

Comment: javascript running on a webserver is not able to connect to a sql database. You would need some additional PHP for that if you just have the webspace and nothing else.

Comment: so i would have to install nodeJs on the server, to communicate  with the db?